# What is the standard response for successful http request for json format without body?

Tags: iphone, json, http, response

I had some trouble with the title, sorry.

I'm having a discussion with a server gal from my work, we're developing iphone application
on REST json standard, now the discussion is, that she said that if i send a request
to the server, she can return response code 200 (ok) and empty body. i think
that she need send 200, AND empty json {} in the body.

Is there a wrong or right here? or it's just a design issue we have to agree on?

Thanks a lot

Comment: imho, the http status code should be left alone and used to signal errors at the http level, and any service-level errors put into the json object. others here think the opposite. there's no right/wrong, as long you keep it consistent.

Comment: @MarcB: No; the whole point of REST is to utilize HTTP, including status codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send a `204 No Content` response with no body and no `Content-Type`.

Comment: I told her that and she said that 204 code says the there's NO body. 200 say that a body may or may not be present. is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

200 can of course be used with a Content-Length of 0. The question here is whether an empty body is a valid instance of the application/json media type (see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt). I believe the answer to that is: "no".